# Compare and sort java 2Darray using an element from the subarray

Tags: java

```
void sortPrice () throws IOException {
            //create a bufferedReader and user scanner
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("items.txt"));
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            List lines = new ArrayList();
            //create a 2D arrayList and append each line of the txt file into a sub-array in the 2D array
            for(String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()){
                String[] currentLine = line.split(",");
                lines.add(currentLine);
            }
String[][] strings = (String[][]) lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()][]);
```

I have this code that read from items.txt file and turn it into 2d array

> I001-2001, Dell XPS 17,5.5, Laptop

> I002-1988, Macbook Pro 15, 8.5, Laptop

> I003-1992, Samsung Galaxy S22, 4.5, Phone
> I004-1999, Iphone 13 PM, 7.5, Phone

> I005-2015, Harman Kardon, 3.5, Earbud

This is what inside the file TXT. I want to sort the item by the third element inside this sub-array which is the price for the item, but since I created the array as the String, it cannot be sort with interger value, I'm new to java so sorry for any techinicality.

Comment: There is no need to create 2D array since you can sort list of rows directly `lines.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(row -> Double.parseDouble(row[2])))`. You just need to declare list to be list of String[] like `List<String[]> lines` so compiler could safely assume that `row` is `String[]` and allow to use `arr[2]`. BUT better solution would be creating class like Product and create `List<Product>`. Then your code could look like `products.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Product::getPrice))` where `getPrice` would return `double`. Such code would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a helper function `Arrays.sort` ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)).

It takes two arguments, an array of things (technically objects, in practice, anything including other arrays), and a custom comparator as a second parameter.

Therefore, you can create a custom comparator like this:

```java
public class MyProductComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
 
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] prod1, String[] prod2) {
        // Compare the element at index 2 of both arrays
        return prod1[2].compareTo(prod2[2]);
    }
}
```

Afterward, you can use it like this:

```java
Arrays.sort(strings, new MyProductComparator());
```

Additionally, java already provides some standard comparator implementations, for example, one that takes two elements and compares them based on a predefined key.
This is quite useful and simplifies your code greatly.

```java
// compare using  the second element
Arrays.sort(strings, Comparator.comparing(o -> o[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Files.lines` will read in the file and put each line in a stream for processing.  The lines can then be sorted before collecting into a list.

- map the lines to an `Abstract.SimpleEntry` to hold the actual line as the key and the double as the value on which to sort.
- The value is split on comma, trimmed of whitespace and retrieved as item 2.  Then converted to a Double.
- then sort the stream using the entry's value.

```
void sortPrice () throws IOException {
   list = Files.lines(Path.of("f:/items.txt"))
        .map(item -> new SimpleEntry<String, Double>(item,
                Double.parseDouble(
                        item.split(",")[2].trim())))
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
}

list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
I005-2015, Harman Kardon, 3.5, Earbud
I003-1992, Samsung Galaxy S22, 4.5
001-2001, Dell XPS 17,5.5, Laptop
Phone I004-1999, Iphone 13 PM, 7.5, Phone
I002-1988, Macbook Pro 15, 8.5, Laptop
```

**Note:**  if you are going to make use of these fields, it would be best to create a class to hold them in their final converted types.